# Notepad++ delete everything in entire large file before and after a variable

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have large text files with all kinds of characters, symbols and numbers. Can I use notepad++ to batch work through a directory of these and delete everything before and after a variable?

I need to find this VARIABLE, which will either be a number or text, and delete everything before AND after it. The text immediately to the left and right will be the same, it will always be "col set 001" and "thursday." with the viariable in between. There will be many lines of random text and characters before and after col set 001 and thursday.

the string is:

`random random randomrandom random randomrandom random randomrandom random randomrandom random random<col set 001">VARIABLE<thursday> random random randomrandom random randomrandom random randomrandom random randomrandom random randomrandom random random`

The resulting file should be a txt file with ONLY one number, or word in it, the variable, different in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression in NPP to find and replace a pattern in all files of a given subfolder, recursively.
Type Ctrl-H to open the Search&Replace dialog, choose the tab "Find in files" and enter

```
Find what: ^.+?<col set 001"?>(.+?)<thursday>.*$
Replace with: \1
Search mode: Regular Expression
tick ". matches newline"
```

The regex matches any characters (`.+`) but as few as possible (`?`) up to the literal string "`<col set 001>`", then any string (`.+?`), again non-greedy, up to the literal "`<thursday>`", followed by anything up to the end-of-file `.*$`.

I have included the option that the "001" ends with a quotation mark although I think it might be a typo. You can leave out the `".` if this is the case.

The replacement is what is matched between the `()` in the search pattern, i.e. the VARIABLE text.

Comment: That " was a typo sorry. Hi, tried this it deletes everythging including the variable...

Comment: I dont think its working because the whole expression is over two lines. What symbol do i put at the linebreak?

Comment: HI, I got that working now. I am now trying to do it for the other values, so that i have the variables all on seperate lines...